# TypeError when trying to iterate and compare values in a list and dict

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a list that is an import of a json and a dict where I want to store the values of the list in the value place. The problem is that when I loop over the list and do a comparative if statement I get this error message

```
if i["service"] == serviceIp[i]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The dict where I would like to store the addresses for the services

```
serviceIp = {
    "service-A": "",
    "service-B": ""
}
```

The list import from json which includes all the addresses

serviceAddress

```
[{'service': 'service-A', 'address': ['localhost1']}, {'service': 'service-B', 'address': ['localhost2']}]
```

This is my loop and if statement

```
for i in serviceAddress:
        if i["service"] == serviceIp[i]:
```

Any idea what is causing this error? My goal is to compare the keys for service and store the service values into the values of the dict

Comment: show the full code causing the error, and the full error

Comment: You can't index a dict with a dict as the key. `i` is a dict, and you're indexing `serviceIp` with it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `if` statement? You're missing something important. `i` is the dict itself, you can't index a list with a dictionary. That's what the `TypeError` is being thrown.  It's expecting a number.

Comment: @PYer Not exactly: `i` is indexing a dict, not a list. It doesn't necessarily expect a number: anything hashable will work.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks, I read the code wrong, I see what the code is trying to do now. Confused `serviceAdress` and `serviceIP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` value in the for loop is a dict. ex: `{'service': 'service-A', 'address': ['localhost1']}` and can't be used as keys for dict.

If you want to store addresses for service names in dict you can do this:

```py
for s in serviceAddress:
    serviceIp[s["service"]] = s["address"]
```

Or if you wan't to make sure to only add services that their names are already in the `serviceIp` dict:

```py
for s in serviceAddress:
    if s["service"] in serviceIp:
       serviceIp[s["service"]] = s["address"]
```

Comment: `if s["service"] in serviceIp:` is enough: `in` (or `__contains__` works on the keys automaticlaly for a dict.